# Image inside custom view doesn't get live rendered

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, swift3, xcode8

I'm building a custom UIView for something like a bar for navigation and want to display this bar inside the view controller in my storyboard.
The bar has two parts. One UIView for the background and one UIImageView for the wave image. My problem is, that if I use that custom view inside my storyboard, only the background UIView get's live rendered and the image does not. If I setup an `@IBInspectable` for an image and set it to the UIImageView in the inspector, it works.

Here is what the bar looks like:

[image: Bar1]

That's how it looks like in the view controller:
[image: Bar2]

Here is my code (Swift 3):

**TopBar.swift**

```
@IBDesignable
class TopBar: UIView {

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        initView()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        initView()
    }

    func initView() {
        let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
        let nib = UINib(nibName: "TopBar", bundle: bundle)
        let view = nib.instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil).first as! UIView

        view.frame = bounds
        view.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]

        addSubview(view)
    }
}
```

Comment: What's height of `view`?

Comment: The background view is 52 and the image is 14

Comment: try with background view height 30 and image 14

Comment: That's not an option. I want exactly that heights. The complete custom view should be 66 in height.

Comment: can you show that view controller in storyboard?

Comment: I did. Look at picture 2 in my question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147707/discussion-between-piyush-patel-and-kai-kuhlmann).

Comment: @KaiKuhlmann check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many discussions with Reinier Melian and many trial and error, I just figured out what caused the problem.

In my Assets.xcassets folder I imported the images I'm using for iPhone device only. After setting this to **Universal** in the inspector, everything worked with my code listed in my question.

Anyways, **big thanks** to Reinier Melian for helping me!
(https://stackoverflow.com/users/6190582/reinier-melian)

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing your awakeFromNib method and add prepareForInterfaceBuilder method

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.initView()
}

override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
    super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    self.initView()
}
```

**EDITED**

It's weird because I use this class all the time and works just fine rendering in my storyboard

```
import UIKit

@IBDesignable class GenericXibView: UIView {

    @IBInspectable var nibName:String?
    /**
     View name.
     */
    func getNibName() ->String?
    {
        return nibName
    }

    /**
     View itself.
     */
    var vView : UIView!;

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.setup()
    }

    /**
     Class construct. Initialize the view.
     */
    public override init(frame oFrame: CGRect) {

        super.init(frame: oFrame);
        self.setup();
    }

    /**
     Class construct. Initialize the view.
     */
    public required init?(coder oDecoder: NSCoder) {

        super.init(coder: oDecoder);
        self.setup();
    }

    /**
     Initialize the custom view and add it to this.
     */
    fileprivate func setup() {

        assert(self.getNibName() != nil, "View with empty nib name can't be instatiated")

        self.vView = UINib(nibName: self.getNibName()!, bundle: Bundle(for: type(of: self))).instantiate(withOwner: self, options: nil)[0] as! UIView;

        self.vView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false;

        self.addSubview(vView);

        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":self.vView]));
        self.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-0-[view]-0-|", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions(rawValue: 0), metrics: nil, views: ["view":self.vView]));

        //        self.vImgUser.layer.cornerRadius  = (self.vImgUser.frame.size.width / 2);
        //        self.vImgUser.layer.masksToBounds = true;
        self.setNeedsLayout();
    }

    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        setup()
        vView.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
    }

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */

}
```

Also make sure that your class is setted as fileOwner in your xib file

Hope this helps

Comment: Those two methods don't change anything. Yes I have set the File's Owner custom class to TopBar.swift

Comment: Check my edited answer, and also check if you have marked Atomatically Refresh Views in Editor Xcode Menu

Comment: I tried your code, but the image is still not shown in the view controller. "Automatically Refresh Views" is checked. It is weird that if I use an @IBInspectable and set the image manually in die view controller inspector, it shows up immediately...

Comment: Try calling yourImage.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()

Comment: Not working. Is there a way to at the image manually in awakeFromNib() or something like that as a workaround?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147723/discussion-between-reinier-melian-and-kai-kuhlmann).